# How to load and use APIs properly in React apps?

Tags: reactjs

I have some performance issue on my server. This is my root App component's container. This container is called every time users comes to the main page of my website, which means the system keeps requesting the APIs everytime someone comes to my website.

However, I think this takes a lot of memory on my server. I recently started using REST APIs in Django REST Framework with React js. Every time I request APIs, should I do something or store them somewhere so that I don't need to request again when they come back to the main page again?

**container.js**

```js
class Container extends Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getStores();
    this._getImages();
  }

  _getStores = async () => {
    const stores = await this._callStoreApi();
    this.setState({
      stores
    });
  };

  _callStoreApi = () => {
    return fetch("/boutiques/stores/")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => json)
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  };

  _getImages = async () => {
    const randomImages = await this._callImageApi();
    this.setState({
      randomImages
    });
  };

  _callImageApi = () => {
    return fetch("/boutiques/random-feed-images/")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => json)
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  };

  render() {
    const { stores, randomImages } = this.state;

    return (
      <DocumentMeta {...head}>
        <div>
          {stores && randomImages ? (
            <App {...this.props} stores={stores} randomImages={randomImages} />
          ) : (
            <Loader />
          )}
        </div>
      </DocumentMeta>
    );
  }
}

export default Container;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better you implement some kind of cache of your data. you can write a service like the following to cache your data whenever you need.

> Note: the following code is just for example purpose, it may need many
>   improvements before it can be used in production.

**APIService.js:**

```
let cache = {};
class APIService {
  fetch(url, options = {}) {
    let cacheStatus = this.cacheStatus;
    this.cacheStatus = false;
    let cacheKey = url + JSON.stringify(options);
    if (cacheStatus && cache[cacheKey]){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(cache[cacheKey]));
    }

    return fetch(url, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (cacheStatus) {
          cache[cacheKey] = response;
        }
        return response;
      });
  }

  cache(status) {
    this.cacheStatus = status;
    return this;
  }
}

const API = new APIService();
export default API;
```

then you can import it where you need:

```
import API from "./APIService.js";
```

and try to call the api like the following:

```
await API.cache(true).fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
await API.cache(true).fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
await API.cache(true).fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
```

you can see it will call the api only once. if you dont want cache then just call the api as usual.

so the idea is to keep the data cache in the browser memory and return it from the cache whenever needed. but if page is reloaded then it will fetch fresh data.

You can get the idea from the code.

i used codesandbox.io to write the code. you can check the code on the following link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/rrwv7xxj3n